# "My interest in becoming" vs. "my interest to become"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, letter-writing, gerund-vs-infinitive

I was writing a letter of application for a university. I wanted to start my letter by writing:

> I am writing this letter to express my interest in becoming part...

and then I got confused. I am not sure how the last part of that sentence should be.

> - ...in becoming part...
> - ...to become part...

What is the semantic difference between the two variants?

Comment: Becoming part is better.  It is the present progressive tense vs the infinitive.

Comment: Perhaps you'd be better off using simpler sentences, and not trying to show your English off in an application letter. You get no difficulty points for attempting complex phraseology, nor for stating the obvious. There's enough of that already in academic life. How about _I wish to apply for admission to your `X` degree program in `Y`_?

Comment: @JohnLawler sure, I am always a fan of simplicity over complexity, but still I wonder what is the correct form here...

Comment: _Interest(ed)_ takes prepositional phrases with _in_, which can have gerund clauses as objects (_He's interested in logographic pyrology, his interest in pyrographic logology_), but they don't take infinitive clauses (_*He's interested to leave now,_ _*his interest to leave now_)

Comment: Not enough context.

Answer (score 2):

As John Lawler notes in a comment,

> *Interest(ed)* takes prepositional phrases with *in*, which can have gerund clauses as objects (*He's interested in logographic pyrology*, *his interest in pyrographic logology*), but they don't take infinitive clauses (**He's interested to leave now*, **his interest to leave now*)

This means "interest in becoming" is the appropriate choice. Similar examples:

> I am interested in becoming part of...
>
> Allow me to express my interest in becoming part of...
>
> I am interested in leaving at 5 o' clock.

More information on [gerunds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerunds) can be found at Wikipedia.

Comment: Though of course *It is in his interest to leave now* is perfectly normal.

Answer (score -1):

Often, the K.I.S.S. principle is useful, and you could go with simple present and infinitives:

> I write this letter to express my interest to become part of ...

However, the use of simple-present tense - although technically correct - is [fast fading](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20write%20to%20you,%20I%20am%20writing%20to%20you&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,I%20write%20to%20you;,c0;.t1;,I%20am%20writing%20to%20you;,c0). Best to retain the present perfect:

> I am writing this letter to express my interest in becoming part of ...

But if this is the problem you are having in writing your application letter, perhaps first put a mind to issues of [tone](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/652/1/).

Comment: -1: First, nobody uses *"express my interest to become ... "*. [Evidence](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=express+my+interest+in%2C+express+my+interest+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cexpress%20my%20interest%20in%3B%2Cc0). Second, there is no need for these verb tenses to agree. You would say *"expressing my desire to become ..."* and *"expressing my interest in becoming ..."*, no matter what verb tenses were used earlier.

Comment: I wouldn't have said, "nobody uses"; the use of the present progressive over the simple present tense is definitely far more common, but is it not incorrect. It is, without a doubt, dated and not in common use, but it is [correct if fading](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+write+to+you%2C+I+am+writing+to+you&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20write%20to%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20am%20writing%20to%20you%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: You are misunderstanding me completely. The distinction in question is between "interest to become" and "interest in becoming". That is, whether you use the infinitive or the present progressive ***after "interest"***.

Comment: Sorry about the misunderstanding. Your evidence is, IMO, focused on the wrong part of the phrase. Look instead at ["my interest to become"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=my+interest+in+becoming%2Cmy+interest+to+become&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmy%20interest%20in%20becoming%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmy%20interest%20to%20become%3B%2Cc0). Fewer, but not "nobody." As to the 2nd part of your original comment, you are right: there is no *need* for the use of the gerund in both cases, since neither it nor the infinitive are conjugated.

Comment: I'd also ditch ***"I write this letter" or "I am writing this letter"*** since that part is obvious and does not apply the K.I.S.S. principle.

Comment: what would you add to the beginning then?

Comment: @WolfgangKuehne Nothing at all. "Dear Sir or Madam: I am interested in becoming ..." That's all you need.